# Show that the intersection of any d-systems is again a d-system

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

This is probably straight-forward by I'm lame with proofs and sets. How can i show that the intersection of any d-systems (Dynkin systems) is again a d-system?

Here is the definition of a Dynkin system.

A collection $\mathcal{D}$ of sub-sets of $S$ where:

(1) $S \in \mathcal{D}$

(2) If $E_1,E_2 \in \mathcal{D}$ where $E_1 \subset E_2$ then $E_2 \setminus E_1 \in \mathcal{D}$

(3) If $E_n \in \mathcal{D}$ and $E_n \subset E_{n+1}$ for any $n$, then $\bigcup_n E_n \in \mathcal{D}$

Comment: Maybe you can add a list of properties for Dynkin systems and mention which you have already shown and which are still unclear for you.

Comment: This is really straight-forward...what exactly are your difficulties?

Comment: I think I get lost in the formality. So, I guess I have to pick two arbitrary collections that are d-systems.Then I have to work through the definition of a d-system

Comment: So do it step by step.  It sounds like you want to start with the intersection of two d-systems, which is fine.  But then you also will need to do the intersection of more d-systems, including infinitely many of them.

Comment: Thanks. @GEdgar! My reasoning actually was that if I do it for arbitrary two d-systems and show that their intersection is again a d-sytem, this will prove it. Do I have to show this for infinitely many?

Comment: here is my reasoning for example for proving point (2) from the definition above. Let's assume that E and F are two subsets such that $E \subset F$ and $E, F \in \mathcal{D_1}$ and $E, F \in \mathcal{D_2}$ where $\mathcal{D_{1,2}}$ are d-systems with intersection $\mathcal{D}$. Since $F\E \in \mathcal{D_{1,2}}$ (because they lie in a d-system) then $F\E \in \mathcal{D}$, which proves the second point. It all looks good to me but I'm not sure if I can safely assume that those two sets $E \subset F$ exist at the intersection of $\mathcal{D_1}$ and $\mathcal{D_2}$. Am I applying circular logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All such intersection arguments go the same way (i.e. the intersection of a set of $\sigma$-algebras is a $\sigma$-algebra, ditto for topologies etc.):

Let $\mathcal{D}_i$, $i \in I$ be any family of Dynkin-systems on a set $S$.

Then $\mathcal{D} = \bigcap_i \mathcal{D}_i$ is also a Dynkin-system:

1. We know that for all $i \in I$, $S \in \mathcal{D}_i$, as each $\mathcal{D}_i$ is a Dynkin system. So by the definition of intersection, $S \in \mathcal{D}$, as required.
2. Suppose $E_1 \subseteq E_2$ where $E_1, E_2 \in \mathcal{D}$. Let $i \in I$ be arbitary. We know that $E_1, E_2 \in \mathcal{D}_i$ (again definition of intersection), and as $\mathcal{D}_i$ is a Dynkin system, we know that $E_2\setminus E_1 \in \mathcal{D}_i$. As this works for all arbitary $i$, $E_2 \setminus E_1 \in \mathcal{D}$, as required.
3. Now suppose $E_n$ is an increasing sequence of subsets from $\mathcal{D}$. Then fix $i \in I$ again. We know that all $E_n$ are in particular in $\mathcal{D}_i$ and as this is given to be a Dynkin system, $\bigcup_n E_n \in \mathcal{D}_i$, and as $i$ was arbitary, $\bigcup_n E_n \in \mathcal{D}$, as required.

We checked all axioms so $\mathcal{D}$ is a Dynkin system.